# Has anyone seen the word or the characters in the word "" used before?

Tags: usage, characters, literary-chinese

According to Wiktionary,  is an adjective pronounced "juéjié" in Mandarin and means "moving"([https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/#Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A0%84%91%F0%A0%84%8D#Chinese)). Somebody on the page has hypothesized that the pronunciation is borrowed from "孑孓". The alternative forms "" and "" are also listed. Has/could somebody use this term in a sentence? I checked Chinese Text Project (https://ctext.org/), but it seems it is only listed in the Kangxi dictionary.

Comment: All my browsers on Android don't show these characters. They show rectangles with X. Any help?

Comment: @Konstantinos it is normal not to show very rare charactes, they are too rare for some electronics, perhaps not in the big 5 character base.  For reference my newest iphone also shows nothing.

Comment: @zagrycha, I don't think it's about the phone or its os. It looks like it is more about the browser or the app (google docs etc.). What is the best browser or an extension for seeing any possible Chinese character?

Comment: @Konstantinos as far as I am aware it is the technology itself as they are not programmed to input or show such rare characters.  Even in chinese places many devices, websites, and browsers etc. do not render such characters.  In that case many are written by pinyin like bei for break.  A more formal example is inserting a photo of the character, as newspapers frequently have to do for a taiwanese politician with a rare character in his name.

Answer (score 1):

The word 屯丩 comes from 《六書略》. In 《集韻》 the order is reversed and the word becomes 丩屯.

In 《說文》 the two "hooks" in 屯丩 can be found in the following entries:

> 鉤識也。从反亅。讀若窡。

> 鉤逆者謂之亅。象形。凡亅之屬皆从亅。讀若橜。

屯丩 consist of both a 亅 (hook) and a 反亅 (reversed hook), hence used to represent a person's moving.

The term is no longer used in modern Chinese. It is not related to 彳亍、踟蹰、踟躇、跢跦、辗转、踌躇、辵辵、周章、施施、首施、次且. In fact, it's rarely used in Classical Chinese as well.
[image: pic].

P.S. The character 丩 first appeared as "顛" ("upside down") in "顛隕" ("downfall"). 丩 was in the shape of an upside-down human figure. It then gradually went out of use. The use of 丩 in 屯丩 was probably unrelated to the earliest 丩.

P.P.S. The true characters cannot be displayed here so 丩 and 屯 are used instead.

Reference:
謝明文《釋“顛”字》